# Use R to Scrape Information from Planned Parenthood Website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying use the rvest library to scrape certain information from a planned parenthood website. The webpage that I am looking at is [here](https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tennessee/knoxville/37914/knoxville-health-center-2610-91550). I am currently trying to pull the Services Offered on the right side of the webpage such as "abortion services", "birth control", etc. I have the following code below which is close?

```
 URL <- "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tn"
  Webpage <- read_html(URL)
  all_links <- Webpage %>% 
    html_nodes("p a") %>%
    html_attr('href') %>%
    paste0('https://www.plannedparenthood.org', .)
 URL <- all_links[1]
 Website <- URL
 Webpage <- read_html(URL)
 Services <- Webpage %>% html_nodes("ul li a") %>% html_attr("href")
```

I start at the main planned parenthood page and navigate to the first facility in TN. Can someone help me obtain the services offered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
URL <- "https://www.plannedparenthood.org/health-center/tn"
Webpage <- read_html(URL)
all_links <- Webpage %>% 
  html_nodes("p a") %>%
  html_attr('href') %>%
  paste0('https://www.plannedparenthood.org', .)
URL <- all_links[1]
Website <- URL
Webpage <- read_html(URL)
Services <- Webpage %>% html_nodes(".services a") %>% html_text()
```

Which gives:

```
> Services
[1] "Abortion Services"                            "Birth Control"                                "HIV Testing"                                  "LGBTQ Services"                              
[5] "Men's Health Care"                            "Morning-After Pill (Emergency Contraception)" "Pregnancy Testing & Services"                 "STD Testing, Treatment & Vaccines"           
[9] "Women's Health Care"
```

I only changed this in the last line `%>% html_nodes(".services a") %>% html_text()`

So I used a more specific css selector and then only took the html text that resulted from this selector.

If you are not familiar with CSS try [this](https://selectorgadget.com/) Google Chrome Addon which makes getting the right CSS selector more easy.

Comment: Wow, so simple. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link. I have that downloaded. When I use it though and click on abortion services... I just get an "a".

Comment: Yes me too. You then have to make sure that no other parts of the website  that you do not want to select are highlighted in yellow. You can do that by clicking on the yellow areas that you don't want until the only highlighted item (may now be green) is the one you actually want.

Comment: Ahhhhh got it! Thanks so much!

Comment: So to get the list of accepted insurance under "Insurance and Payments"... I tried Webpage %>% html_nodes("li:nth-child(1)").. which didn't really work.